# about isomorphic between polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

let $k$ be algebraic close field , why following rings are isomorphic ?

$k[x, y] /\left(y-x^{2}\right) \cong k\left[x, x^{2}\right] \cong k[x]$

i need theorem for general case for example when $k[x, y] /\left(f(x,y)\right)  \cong k[x]$ ? for what $f(x,y)$ this is true ?

Comment: The general case is likely to be quite difficult. Taking specs, we see that this is the case if and only if $C = V(f(x,y))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. Hence we get a way of showing when this is not the case: if $C$ not smooth or if $C$ is smooth and $g(C) = (d-1)(d-2)/2 \neq 0$ where $d$ is the degree of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an isomorphism $f:k[x]\to k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ sending $x\mapsto x$. The inverse homomorphism is $g:k[x,y]/(y-x^2)\to k[x]$ sending $x\mapsto x$ and $y\mapsto x^2$.

Note that this does not require $k$ to be algebraically closed.

Comment: for $k\left[x, x^{2}\right] \cong k[x]$ what is isomorphism ?

Comment: They are equal. Check both inclusions, looking at the definition of a polynomial ring.